# ASP.NET Core 3 API routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

So I've created an API project using .NET Core 3 and inside the project I've created a Controller like so:

```
[Route("api/account")]
[ApiController]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
   public IActionResult Hello()
   {
      return Ok("Hello");
   }
}
```

In my `Startup.cs` I have:

```
public class Startup
{
   public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

   public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
   {
      Configuration = configuration;
   }

   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
      services.AddControllers();
   }

   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
   {
      app.UseRouting();
      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
      {
         endpoints.MapControllers();
      });
    }
}
```

From what I understand, the line `services.AddControllers();` picks up every controller in my api project. I remember in asp.net to add controllers you would have to call this line:

`services.AddTransient<AccountController>();`

You would have to namely add each controller, is there no way to do this in .NET Core 3?

Comment: Is the issue that you can't hit your endpoint? - services.AddTransient<AccountController>(); is specifically DI and is not standard in .NET framework

Comment: @GlynnHurrell I can hit the endpoint, but removing app.UseEndpoints() won't allow me to hit the endpoints. I was thinking of a scenario where if I didn't want certain endpoints to be hit, how would I specify each controller to be used by the api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want that certain endpoints should not be hit, MVC provide provision to use attribute **[NonAction]**:

```
[NonAction]
public IActionResult Index()
```

The end points for which the attribute is used, would not be hit in the API call.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to expose an action method(end point) to client, you can make the method as "private" or as Imran suggested, you can decorate the method with "[NonAction]" attribute.